# Entity framework Handle procedure returning Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework

My Stored procedure returns data in json format.
Eg.

```
{
  "StoryData": [
    {
      "UserStoryId": 141204
     }]
}
```

How can I take this in json format from Entity frameworkside?

I tried :-

```
using (MyWizard_ARA_AppEntities context = new MyWizard_ARA_AppEntities())
                {
                    log.Info("Database connected successfully");
                    log.Info("GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT procedure called");                    
                    return context.GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT().ToArray();
                }
```

But it was not giving me proper result.

Please help.

**EDIT :-**

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<string> GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT");
        }
```

Comment: *not giving me proper result.* - what result is it giving you? What were you expecting? If it returns a string (which is *what json is*) and you want an object, then you are going to need to deserialize it after retrieving it.

Comment: I am expecting json as I am receiving from stored procedure which I have shown in my example

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - *what are you getting now*?

Answer (score 1):

You should deserialize returning json result from `GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT` procedure to object;

```
using (MyWizard_ARA_AppEntities context = new MyWizard_ARA_AppEntities())
{
    log.Info("Database connected successfully");
    log.Info("GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT procedure called");
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ambiguityanalysis>(context.GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT());
    return result;
}

public class StoryData
{
    public int UserStoryId { get; set; }
}

public class Ambiguityanalysis
{
    public List<StoryData> StoryData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, you aren't "returning json result" you are returning an object of type `Ambiguityanalytsis`, but I suspect that's actually what the OP really wants.

Comment: can not convert objectresult<string> to string

Comment: "GET_AMBIGUITYANALYSIS_RESULT()" method doesn't return directly json result as string ? You should use SingleOrDefault in the method to retrieve only single item from procedure result.